# server client in android

Tags: php, android

I try to send some request from android emulator to a php server. I tried this code.

```
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url); 
UrlEncodedFormEntity ent = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params,HTTP.UTF_8);
post.setEntity(ent);
HttpResponse responsePOST = client.execute(post);  
HttpEntity resEntity = responsePOST.getEntity();  
InputStream in=resEntity.getContent();
in.close();
```

here I need to read some xml data as inputstream. But I don't have enough knowledge in php. So can you explain me how looks like my php code to send xml data to android emulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to have PHP print the xml data, if it's being dynamically generated.

If it's a static XML file then there's no reason to bother with PHP, just store the file on the server and retrieve the file.

Comment: I do not have any idea to retrieve the xml file on php server. can u give an example how to do that

Comment: What is the name of the server software, then? For example: Apache, Nanoweb ... ?